# How do we set up an application (SP) to use the centralized company IdP in SAML in PHP?

Tags: php, saml, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp, service-provider

We have several PHP based applications at our organization. The three in question connect to our organizations SAML IdP. These except for one were all out-of-the-box applications which had the SAML stuff built in.

We have a third application which is kind of a one-off, but it has no SAML set up for it currently. We have loaded and started configuring SimpleSAMLphp, and I have also been provided the metadata by the people that govern the IdP.

I know that one of the points of SAML is to keep the SP applications from seeing the users credentials, but also obviously for SSO functionality.

My questions are:

- When a user clicks our 'Login' link to go to our login page, what do we need to do to direct the user to the IdP login page - and additionally send them back to the SP?
- I did see through some debugging of another app of ours, that there is a Saml Request that is generated and POST'ed to the end point. I assume that this is the answer to my first question, but I am not sure how to generate that Saml Request.

What do we need to do to basically make this application live as just a Service Provider? We don't need to set up any IdP here.

Answer (score 0):

> - When a user clicks our 'Login' link to go to our login page, what do we need to do to direct the user to the IdP login page - and additionally send them back to the SP?

The admin of the IdP will give you information on how to access (and use) the IdP. One example would be a simple redirect URL the user have to open or redirected to. Then the authentication takes places between the user and the IdP. This will take "outside" of your control or service.

At some point later the user will be redirected back to a pre-configured URL on your service. The access point must exist on your service and it has been communicated before hand to the admin of the IdP. The admin has to set this "return URL" in the IdP. The request from the IdP on your service access point will contain a SAML response from the IdP (a XML document). You have to parse this SAML response, check if it is valid and extract the user identification from it. Then you know who exactly wants to use your service and can use this information in your service.

> - I did see through some debugging of another app of ours, that there is a Saml Request that is generated and POST'ed to the end point. I assume that this is the answer to my first question, but I am not sure how to generate that Saml Request.

Depending on the IdP you might not need to create a SAML request. You can simply redirect the user to the IdP's login page. But that depends on the configuration of the IdP for your service.